# Forward Chaining using variables in rules in CLIPS

Tags: clips

So, I'm trying to make a "golf club recommendation system" for a 18 hole course. Now, after having defined the basic templates for the golfcourse, golf club and the golf player, I'm stuck due to the large search space this particular problem presents. So currently I have:

```
(defrule teeoff
   ?g <- (golfer (position "tee"))
   => 
   (retract ?g)
   (assert (golfer (position "fairway") (Current_club "driver") (Yardage 650))
```

After this, the ball is on fairway and can have a combination of factors say, it can be on sand, it can be on rough or it could be on a normal green. My question is instead of making a rule for every possibility can I have one or two rules like:

```
(defrule makemove
   ?m <- (golfer (position ?x))
   ?go <- (golfcourse (obstacles ?$y)
=> 
   (assert (golfer (Current_club ?c)))
```

If not, then what alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to design an object or attribute to manage the ground_material (sand, green, ...) and include it inside the rule.
You can write rule for each ground or use IF-THEN condition inside a single rule.

Hope this helps you.
bye
Nic